# How to find area of a polygon built on the roots of a given polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

How to find the area of a (maximum area convex) polygon, built on the roots of a given polynomial in the complex plane?

For example, consider the equation:

$$2x^5+3x^3-x+1=0$$

It has one real and four complex roots and makes a nice convex pentagon in the complex plane (thanks, Wolfram Alpha):

[image]

Using the formula for the area of a convex polygon:

$$A=\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{array}| x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{array} + \begin{array}| x_2 & x_3 \\ y_2 & y_3 \end{array} + \dots +  \begin{array}| x_n & x_1 \\ y_n & y_1 \end{array} \right)$$

I obtained for this case (using numerical values of the roots):

$$A=1.460144\dots$$

---

Another simple case - roots of unity. They just make regular polygons and the general formula for the area is well known.

---

> However, I would like to know if it's possible to find out this area without computing the roots, using only the coefficients of the polynomial? (The coefficients are meant to be rational).

I know that polynomials with only real roots will all have $A=0$, and for the polynomials with several real roots some of them will be inside our maximum area polygon.

There is a useful theorem (see [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) ), according to which:

> For a monic polynomial $$z^n+a_{n-1} z^{n-1}+\dots+a_1 z+a_0$$
>
> All its roots will be located inside the circle $|z|=1+\max |a_k|$.

But this theorem gives relatively large area, and can't be used to approximate the area of the polygon.

Comment: I doubt this is directly helpful, but a somewhat related problem would be to calculate the area of the Minkowski sum of $[-r_i,r_i]$ where $r_i$ are the roots enumerated with duplicity (and such an interval is just the convex hull of the two points - i.e. a symmetrical line segment through the origin), then one can calculate it for a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ as follows: Define $Q_{c}(x)=x^nP(c/x)$. Now, calculate $R(c)=\text{res}(P,Q_c)$ where $\text{res}$ is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant). Then, you sum the absolute value of the imaginary part of each root of $R$

Comment: The area is given by $$ \frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\zeta_j \overline{\zeta_{j+1}}$$ with $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\ldots,\zeta_n,\zeta_{n+1}=\zeta_1$ being the the vertices of the convex envelope of the roots. However, we have to detect which roots lie inside the convex envelope and which roots do not, so I do not think there is a nice closed formula.

Comment: Following up on Jack's remark: In particular, you should not expect a polynomial in the roots, for when one root is strictly inside the convex hull of the others, the area (as a function of the roots) is independent of that root.

Comment: What I mean to say was that the *formula for the area* is unlikely to be a polynomial in the roots (which doesn't seem to be stated between the highlighted areas); it's still possible, of course, that it's a polynomial in the coefficients. Sorry for wasting your time by being unclear.

Comment: @JohnHughes, I see what you mean now, thank you for clarification

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio In the formula for the area, you should take the imaginary part, not the real part (or equivalently, multiply by $i$).

Comment: @Aaron: you're right, but the issue of detecting the vertices inside the convex envelope is still there.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree.  A further complication is that, even if all the roots were vertices of the convex hull, the area formula is not (skew)symmetric in the ordering of the vertices, so it would require additional information beyond, say, the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: Yet Another Complication, incidentally, and a reason to not expect a polynomial in the coefficients, is that polynomial roots are sensitive to coefficients, and so the area of the convex hull can be as well; [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial) is the canonical example of this; the sensitivity of the roots (and thus the area of their hull) to the 'initial conditions' is stronger than you could get out of a polynomial expression in them. This doesn't rule out non-polynomial (e.g. rational) expressions, but it still seems highly unlikely.

Comment: This problem boils down to finding the roots of any given polynomial given coefficients. I doubt there would be a method that analytically does this beyond a quartic.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to attempt your question but i do not understand how you got that area there, i worked mine on maxima.... is there something i missed?
$$A=\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{array}| x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{array} + \begin{array}| x_2 & x_3 \\ y_2 & y_3 \end{array} + \dots +  \begin{array}| x_n & x_1 \\ y_n & y_1 \end{array} \right)$$
$$2x^5+3x^3-x+1=0$$
$\text{allroots(%)}$
$$[x = 0.415380864154341i+0.4410774845527911,x = 0.4410774845527911-0.415380864154341i,x = -0.7513475303185956,x = 1.344822399888639i-0.06540371939349326,x = -1.344822399888639i-0.06540371939349326]$$
$$[y_5:  0.415380864154341, x_5: 0.4410774845527911,x_4: 0.4410774845527911, y_4 : -0.415380864154341,x_3: -0.7513475303185956, y_3: 0, y_2: 1.344822399888639, x_2: -0.06540371939349326, y_1: -1.344822399888639 , x_1 : -0.06540371939349326]$$
$$ A = \frac{x_4y_5-x_1y_5-x_5y_4+x_3y_4-x_4y_3+x_2y_3-x_3y_2+x_1y_2+x_5y_1-x_2y_1}{2}$$
$$A = 0.4735192335485968\dots$$

Comment: I could have made a mistake somewhere, honestly I'm not sure, it's been a long time

Comment: Okay, the question seems interesting to me because I once thought of it.... Perhaps I'll drop an answer soon

Comment: @YuriyS I checked the problem again, but this time I solved it.... The solution seems to be very large, *the area of the polygon is the root of two $120$ degree polynomial* plus I saw why we had different answers, I later got $1.81398\dots$ and $0.396199\dots$ then I realized it's because of the system of choosing the coordinates, in my answer there I choose the coordinates randomly $$.$$ so therefore i plotted the shape myself and was very careful of the coordinate in arranging it into the area formula, this made we believe that $1.813982470359723\dots$ is the true answer...

Comment: @YuriyS the process I used to extract the area as root of a polynomial is large, if you want me to share or answer the question.. recalculate the area you got there

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I will certainly do it as soon as I have the time

Answer (score -1):

The polygon with vertices of roots of a polynomial must be  symmetric about real axis because of the conjugate roots. 
 Area of the polygon equals to 2 times the region in upper half plane.
The formula of area of polygon must be abandoned if polygon area is hoped to be computed with coefficients. This is because that formula requires the vertices of polygon which is impossible to be computed by the coefficients of the polynomial if the degree of the polynomial is equals or higher than 5 due to Abel-Ruffini theorem.
It is possible for us to find out area generated by polynomial of degree 3 or 4(1 and 2 do not give a region) with the coefficients.

Here are some hints.