# Area of a Hexagon in the Complex Plane given by the solutions of $x^6+x-1=0$

Tags: geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I have this problem I friend gave me a little while ago and I don't even know where to begin.

This was the problem he gave me:

Let $z_0, z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5$ be the solutions to the equation $x^6+x-1=0$. Find the area of the hexagon given by $z_0z_1z_2z_3z_4z_5$ in the complex plane.

Also I have no clue how to even tag this problem, so feel free to edit them :)

Comment: You know that given three points $z_1, z_2, z_3$ on the complex plane the area of the triangle defined by these three points is $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Im}[(z_2-z_1)(z_3-z_1)]$.

Comment: Yet another approach is well described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtzGm0J-gSc

Comment: @TedBlack I think you have a typo in that formula. With $z_1=0$, $z_2 = 1+i$, $z_3=1-i$ (say) your formula gives an area of $0$, since $\left(z_2-z_1\right)\left(z_3-z_1\right)$ is real.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Im}[(z_2-z_1)^*(z_3-z_1)]$ its just the sine rule for the area of a triangle

Comment: @TedBlack No, it's not. (Also, I don't think you mean "sine rule" - I assume you mean $\frac12 ab \sin C$) I think you're possibly looking for an analogy with vector cross products that isn't there. Did you check the counterexample I gave? (The triangle has area $1$, but your formula gives $0$.) The simplest form for the area of a triangle given in the complex plane I've seen is in terms of a determinant involving the points and their conjugates.

Comment: The last formula gives an answer equal to -1 not zero! You don't need a determinant to calculate the area of a triangle!!

Comment: @TedBlack I'm not sure what we're missing here. With $z_1=0$, $z_2=1+i$, $z_3=1-i$, your formula is $\frac12 \text{Im} \left(z_2-z_1\right)\left(z_3-z_1\right)=\frac12 \text{Im} (1+i)(1-i)=\frac12 \text{Im} (2+0i)$. The imaginary part of the number $2+0i$ is zero, so the result of your formula is zero. Could you show how you get $-1$?

Comment: @Chris Lewis the updated formula (see comments) was $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Im}[(z_2-z_1)^*(z_3-z_1)]$. Since $z_2-z_1=1+i$ and $z_3-z_1=1-i$ we have $(z_2-z_1)^*(z_3-z_1)=(1-i)(1-i)=-2i$ so $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Im}[(z_2-z_1)^*(z_3-z_1)]=\frac{1}{2}(-2)=-1$. See geometric proof of formula here: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/qf6ytgvb

Answer (score 2):

As $p(x):=x^6+x-1$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, its roots are

- either real :  $\approx -1.1347$ and $\approx 0.7781,$
- or pairs of complex conjugate numbers :  $\approx -0.4511 \pm 1.0024i$ and $\approx 0.6294 \pm 0.7358i.$

Therefore, their representative points are either on the real axis or symmetrical with respect to it. See (red) hexagon on this figure :

[image]

As a consequence, an approximate answer can be obtained by just computing the upper part of the area (above the real axis) as a sum of trapezoidal areas, then double it.

If you look at the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1862189/305862), the opinion expressed there is that no general method exists giving an *exact* answer. You will find there the following formula for the numerical computation of the area :

$$A=\frac12 \Im\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}r_k\overline{r_{k+1}}\right)$$

($\Im$ meaning "imaginary part" ; please note that indices are to be understood "modulo n" in order that  $r_{n+1}=r_1$). This formula isn't especialy interesting here.

**Edit 1 :**

Let us consider the derivative $p'(x)=6x^5+1$ of polynomial $p(x)$. Its $5$ roots $-\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{6}} e^{i2k\pi/5}, \ k=0,1,2,3,4$ form a pentagon included into the hexagon by the celebrated [**Gauss-Lucas theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) ; therefore, the area of the hexagon is larger than the area of the pentagon which can be computed *exactly* (it is an exception !) as $\frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{6^{2/5}}\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}$). *I wonder whether the real question of your friend is indeed to minorate the area of the hexagon...*, unless he just wanted a numerical approximation of the area $A \approx 2.67261847$...

**Edit 2 :**

Some thoughts about the peculiarity of polynomial $p$. The fact that this polynomial has many zero coefficients invites to attempt a factorization :

$$p(x)=(x^2+ax+p)\left(x^4-ax^3+bx^2+cx-\frac{1}{p}\right)\tag{*}$$

where the quadratic factor yields the real roots.

There are 3 constraints on $b$ and $c$ :

$$b=a^2-p, \ c=a(2p-a^2), \ c+a(b-p)=0$$

from which we deduce the following condition linking $a$ and $p$

$$a^4p-3a^2p^2+(p^3+1)=0$$

which can be considered as a quadratic equation in $A:=a^2$.

Therefore, one can express $a$ as a function of $p$. As a consequence, all the coefficients in (*) can be expressed as functions of $p$.

Open question : Can this be used for reaching an exact expression of the area ?

Remark : numerical values of the coefficients of the fourth degree polynomial in (*) can be obtained at once with the very handy function "deconv" of Matlab:

$$    deconv([1,0,0,0,0,1,-1],[1,\underbrace{0.35663453}_a,\underbrace{-0.8829170}_p])$$

Matlab program for the construction of the hexagon above :

> ```
> L=[1,0,0,0,0,1,-1], % list of coefficients
> r=roots(L); 
> [K,A]=convhull(real(r),imag(r)), % convex hull
> r=r(K), % trigonometric ordering of the roots
> plot(r,'-or');
> Implementation of formula (1) :
> s=0;
> for k=1:6
>    s=s+r(k)*conj(r(k+1));
> end;
> imag(s)/2, % area (same value as A, up to the sign)
> ```

Comment: Strange not to have any comment from the asker...